# Find out if you are on localhost or web via script

Tags: php, localhost

I need to check when I am localhost or on the web.

I don't want to use Alias ​​for so many reasons so I would like to succeed with a script. I thought of doing it through servername but ...something is not working.

The main idea:

```
$hostType = getHostType();
function getHostType()
{
  if( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === 'localhost' ) { return 'local';  }
  elseif( isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ) { return 'https'; }
  else { return 'http'; }
}

if( $hostType = 'local')
{
  $serverhost = ('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/myfolder');
  $resources = str_replace('//','/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myfolder/resources');
}
elseif($hostType ='https')
{
  $serverhost ='https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $resources = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources';
}
else
{
  $serverhost = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $resources = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources';
}

echo "hostype: ".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']." -- ".$hostType."  |||| server on: ".$serverhost." ||||| resources on: ".$resources;
```

the script tells me that I am on localhost even seeing the difference of server name.

online and local, print this:

> hostype: mysite.com -- local 
>   server on: h t t p//mysite.com/myfolder"
>   resources on: /home/asfasr/public_html/mysite/resources

---

**Solution**

After several tests I figured out how to split localhost from the web.
The script:

```
<? 


  $protocol = ''.$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'];
  $host = ''.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $servername = ''.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  $pageurl = ''. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $project = explode('/', $pageurl)[1];
  $pagename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);


  //  get host type

  if( $host == 'local' || $servername == 'localhost' )
  {
    $GetHost = ('http://localhost/'.$project.'/');
    $GetFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$project.'/';
    // $GetFile = str_replace('//','/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Seexor/');
  }
  elseif( $protocol == 'https')
  {
    $GetHost ='https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $GetFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  }
  else
  {
    $GetHost = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
    $GetFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/';
  }

?>
```

now you can also take files or media via "$ GetHost" and "$ GetFile"

exemple:
`$myPathFiles = $GetFile.'resources/backend/filestoinclude/';`

`$myPathImage = $GetHost.'resources/imgs/';`

Thanks to those who gave me a hand.

Comment: `elseif('https')` ???? else if WHAT is `'https'`

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: If you created a Virtual Host on your dev server for this site to run in, the folder would be i the same place on every site (A MUCH BETTER IDEA THAN THIS FIDDLE) and you could throw all this code in the bin

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're right ... I corrected.i also added error reporting but it says nothing. And the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking $hostType, but assigning it.
use "===" instead of "="

```
if( $hostType === 'local')
{
  $serverhost = ('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/myfolder');
  $resources = str_replace('//','/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myfolder/resources');
}
elseif($hostType === 'https')
{
  $serverhost ='https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $resources = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources';
}
```

Comment: the fever ...
How could I not have noticed.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks, I also improved it later.